# The content in table exceeds the margins

Tags: tables

I have a table with 6 columns, the first column exceeds when the content is long.

My code is:

```
    \begin{tabular}{|p{35mm}|p{30mm}|p{10mm}|p{10mm}|p{15mm}|p{30mm}|}
    \hline
    Nro. Objetivo Específico & Actividades & Fecha inicio & Fecha Fin & Recursos Necesarios & Resultados a obtener \\

    \hline

    \multirow{6}*{Sophia Loren, nombre artístico de Sofia Villani Scicolonenombre artístico de Sofia Villani Scicolonenombre artístico de Sofia Villani Scicolone (Roma, Reino de Italia, 20 de septiembre de 1934), es una actriz italiana .} & Sophia Loren, nombre artístico de Sofia Villani  & 01-08-2016 & 01-08-2016 & Nodejs- expressjs & Obtener el proyecto base \\
                             & Sophia Loren, nombre artístico de Sofia Villani  & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Nodejs- expressjs} & Sophia Loren, nombre artístico de Sofia Villani \\
                             & Sophia Loren, nombre artístico de Sofia Villani  & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Nodejs- expressjs} & Sophia Loren, nombre artístico de Sofia Villani \\
                             & Sophia Loren, nombre artístico de Sofia Villani  & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Nodejs- expressjs} & Obtener una base de datos mantenible.\\
                             & Sophia Loren, nombre artístico de Sofia Villani  & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Nodejs- expressjs} & Obtener el proyecto base.\\
                             & Sophia Loren, nombre artístico de Sofia Villani  & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Nodejs- expressjs} & Obtener y analizar los resultados.\\

    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

this is result:

[image]

**With the solution of the user @marmot**

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{35mm}|p{30mm}|p{10mm}|p{10mm}|p{15mm}|p{30mm}|}
    \hline
    Nro. Objetivo Específico & Actividades & Fecha inicio & Fecha Fin & Recursos Necesarios & Resultados a obtener \\

    \hline
    \multirow{3}{=}{really think that creating such tables is much easier in ConTeXt than in LaTeX. really think that creating such tables is much easierreally think that creating such tables is much easierFor example} 
    & {really think that creating such tables is much easierFor} & {01-08-2016} & {01-08-2016} & {Javascript} & {really think that creating such tables is much easier}\\
    & {really think that creating such tables is much easier} & {01-08-2016} & {01-08-2016} & {IDE – mysql} & {really think that creating such tables is much easier}\\
    \hline


    \multirow{6}{=}{really think that creating such tables is much easier in ConTeXt than in LaTeX. For example} & Desarrollar un prototipo del proyecto & 01-08-2016 & 01-08-2016 & Nodejs- expressjs & Obtener el proyecto base \\
                             & really think that creating such tables is much easier) & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Nodejs- expressjs} & Objective 1\\
                             & really think that creating such tables is much easier. & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Nodejs- expressjs} & Objective 1\\
                             & really think that creating such tables is much easier & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Nodejs- expressjs} & Objective 1\\
                             & Desarrollar un prototipo del proyecto & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Nodejs- expressjs} & Objective 1\\
                             & really think that creating such tables is much easier) & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Training 1} & Objective 1\\

    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

and result is:

[image]

Comment: I believe that all you need to do is to replace `\multirow{3}{=}` by `\multirow{2}{=}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution (I did not know what table you will use but the principle works equally). The text in `\multirow{2}{}{}` now does not overlap with `\multirow{6}{}{}` because of the space added with `[3\baselineskip]`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % For Spanish accented characters
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{|p{35mm}|p{30mm}|p{10mm}|p{10mm}|p{16mm}|p{30mm}|}
    \hline
    Nro. Objetivo Específico & Actividades & Fecha inicio & Fecha Fin & Recursos Necesarios & Resultados a obtener \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\parbox{35mm}{really think that creating such tables is much easier in ConTeXt than in LaTeX. really think that creating such tables is much easier really think that creating such tables is much easier For example}}
    & {really think that creating such tables is much easier} & {01-08-2016} & {01-08-2016} & {Javascript} & {really think that creating such tables is much easier}\\
    & {really think that creating such tables is much easier} & {01-08-2016} & {01-08-2016} & {IDE – mysql} & {really think that creating such tables is much easier.}\\[3\baselineskip] \hline
    \multirow{6}{\linewidth}{\parbox{35mm}{\vspace{-9mm} really think that creating such tables is much easier in ConTeXt than in LaTeX. For example}} & Desarrollar un prototipo del proyecto & 01-08-2016 & 01-08-2016 & Nodejs- expressjs & Obtener el proyecto base \\
                             & really think that creating such tables is much easier & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Nodejs- expressjs} & Objective 1\\
                             & really think that creating such tables is much easier & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Nodejs- expressjs} & Objective 1\\
                             & really think that creating such tables is much easier & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Nodejs- expressjs} & Objective 1\\
                             & Desarrollar un prototipo del proyecto & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Nodejs- expressjs} & Objective 1\\
                             & really think that creating such tables is much easier) & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Training 1} & Objective 1\\

    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{35mm}|p{30mm}|p{10mm}|p{10mm}|p{15mm}|p{30mm}|}
    \hline
    Nro. Objetivo Específico & Actividades & Fecha inicio & Fecha Fin & Recursos Necesarios & Resultados a obtener \\

    \hline

    \multirow{6}{=}{Sophia Loren, nombre artístico de Sofia Villani Scicolonenombre artístico de Sofia Villani Scicolonenombre artístico de Sofia Villani Scicolone (Roma, Reino de Italia, 20 de septiembre de 1934), es una actriz italiana .} & Sophia Loren, nombre artístico de Sofia Villani  & 01-08-2016 & 01-08-2016 & Nodejs- expressjs & Obtener el proyecto base \\
                             & Sophia Loren, nombre artístico de Sofia Villani  & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Nodejs- expressjs} & Sophia Loren, nombre artístico de Sofia Villani \\
                             & Sophia Loren, nombre artístico de Sofia Villani  & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Nodejs- expressjs} & Sophia Loren, nombre artístico de Sofia Villani \\
                             & Sophia Loren, nombre artístico de Sofia Villani  & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Nodejs- expressjs} & Obtener una base de datos mantenible.\\
                             & Sophia Loren, nombre artístico de Sofia Villani  & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Nodejs- expressjs} & Obtener el proyecto base.\\
                             & Sophia Loren, nombre artístico de Sofia Villani  & {01-08-2016} & 01-08-2016 & {Nodejs- expressjs} & Obtener y analizar los resultados.\\

    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: now exist a new error, my question i edited

Comment: @x-rw I'm sorry to hear that. Unfortunately I can't copy your code because there are some funny characters in. (And you would really help others if you could post a complete MWE.) But I am suspecting that  move the `\multirow{6}{=}` one row down.

Comment: what is MWE? mmm i am not understading

Comment: @x-rw An [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) is a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301), see the links. My above snippet would qualify as MWE as it is a minimal compilable code. (And if you remove the special characters, people like me can copy the code and play with it.)